# Meaning of abelian subquotient

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I was reading an article, somewhere it says that the "abelian subquotients of the group $G$" are .... How does it defined ? For example if we take $G=S_n$, the symmetric group, then what are the abelian subquotients of $G$ ?

Comment: Let $G$ be a group. A subquotient of $G$ is a group of the form $\frac{H}{N}$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$. Obviously, an abelian subquotient is a subquotient which is abelian.

Comment: These are also called *sections* of $G$.